# Guarantee mutual exclusion on access and modification of google sheet data in app script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an app script deployed web app that uses google sheet as a crappy database. I was wondering how I can guarantee mutual exclusion on accessing and modifying data from the app script? (Like a mutex / semaphore)
I was concerned since an instance of the web app cannot share variables (obviously), and I'm not sure that access to google sheet data is fast enough to prevent that problem (like making a semaphore in google sheets)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [LockService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/) to achieve that.

That said, I think you should try to minimize its usage the most you can, to prevent your app from slowing down even more (Apps Script and Sheets are not very fast to begin with). Setup the data in your spreadsheet in a way that you can fetch all you need in one go, and same for setting it back.

Comment: thanks! I'm only incrementing a value once, that's the only locked access it requires. Thank you!